# Label encoding to multi categorical variables in R

Tags: r

I am new in R. My dataset consist categorical variable as "importance" having three categories as "High","Medium","Low" and total observations are 1000 and out this 150 are 'NA'. Now, I want to label encoding of above mentioned variable as "High"=0, "Medium"=1, "Low"=2 and also want to encode 'NA'=3. What I've done so far as:-

```
Data$importance=as.numeric(Data$importance)
```

but this is failed to encode "NA". In python we have library as labelEncoder. So is there any package available in R like this? If not then what is the most specific way to do this for multi categorical variables?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

```
df  = data.frame(label=c("Low","High","Medium",NA,"High"))
df$importance = match(df$label, c("High", "Medium", "Low", NA)) - 1
df
#     label importance
# 1    Low          2
# 2   High          0
# 3 Medium          1
# 4   <NA>          3
# 5   High          0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do encoding in following way as well:

```
y=data.frame("importance"=c("high","low","medium","NA"),stringsAsFactors =   FALSE)
y$importance <- replace(y$importance, y$importance == "high", 0)
y$importance <- replace(y$importance, y$importance == "medium", 1)
y$importance <- replace(y$importance, y$importance == "low", 2)
y$importance <- replace(y$importance, y$importance == "NA", 3)
```

Comment: Does this also works for categorical variables having DataType as 'factor'?

Comment: for the categorical variables having dataType as "factor", you can force them to character using stringAsFactors = FALSE, otherwise replace will generate a warning and won't give desired results. You can change the type of variables with factor type to character using as.character